# Loading DICOM images on XCode via Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dicom

I am new to programming.

I'm looking to add scrollable medical images to an iOS app. From what I've read, it looks like DICOM are large files and work with C++. I'm only looking for basic scrolling functionality. Would my best bet to be to use a DICOM to jpeg converter and then import those images in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

[Imebra](https://imebra.com) is a C++ library, but it provides Objective-C wrappers that can be imported into a Swift projects.

In particular, the header imebra_swift.h provided in the objectivec/include/imebraobjc folder can be added directly to your Swift project.

The objective-c wrappers provide a way to convert the image to a UIImage or a NSImage

Disclosure: I'm the author of Imebra.

Answer (score 0):

The DICOM file is used for various applications, generally big dicoms are cineloops or images with high resolution, like a CT Scanner. X-Ray or ultrasound dicoms are very small, and the compression type can lower more the size

Currently I use many modules in dicom with python language, these modules are based on c++ wrapper classes, Maybe the swift have some mechanism to wrapper c++ class.

The Swift language is very new, and probably have no module of dicom implementation, because dicom protocol is very complex, extensive and is used in many situations like a communication, images, cineloops and patient data

If you want only image, maybe you can get with some cost swift native implementation, but the full development of dicom will dispose a lot of time. This blog (http://dicomiseasy.blogspot.com.br/) is usefull and can help you to understand the dicom protocol.

**Edit:**

In this note from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html, talk about the interoperability between the languages, and in the section *Understanding the Swift Import Process*, have a note:

> You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at the OsiriX viewer software http://www.osirix-viewer.com/Downloads.html.  It runs on iOS and OS X and the source code is available.  It makes use of a number of open source libraries and you can probably use the same libraries in your code.

Comment: Yes, osirix is a great viewer but is implemented in Objective-C